# Does jqGrid's datefmt support JavaScript date formats?

Tags: jqgrid

Does jqGrid's `datefmt` support the [JavaScript date syntax](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format) or only the [PHP date syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)? The [jqGrid documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acolmodel_options) doesn't seem to be clear about the excepted formats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best place to answer on such question is to look in the source code of [the date formatter](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.2.0/js/jquery.fmatter.js#L123). How you can see from [the place](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.2.0/js/jquery.fmatter.js#L192) in the code jqGrid supports only one character formatting syntax from PHP. I personally don't use PHP and would prefer another date format. Moreover having another date format one can easy use [globalization plugin](https://github.com/jquery/globalize).

You can try to place new feature request in the [trirand forum](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/feature-request/). If would be nice to be able to choose format of date as additional jqGrid parameter.